# Onclick background value change to HTML tag in CSS

Tags: jquery, image, background, onclick, src

I have my page setup and navigation in order. I also have my background image appearing correctly. Now my goal is to make the background image change onclick.

My background is achieved in a "general.css" style sheet

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My navigation have its own "nav.css" and "nav.js" and the current click function is

```
$('#action1').click(
    function(){
        if ($('#inner1').height() == 0 )
        $('#inner1').animate({height:'250'},800);
        else  if ($('#inner1').height() == 250 )
        $('#inner1').animate({height:'0'},800);
    }
);
```

I would like when you click action1, action2, or action3 it changes the url of the image under the html style to a UNIQUE background. I will have 3 separate backgrounds for each onclick. (below)

```
background: url(../images/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

If anyone could give me some tips on how to change just the URL value onclick it would be much appreciated. I need the background url to change but not the other styles. Last example below.

```
html { 
  background: url(   CHANGE THIS VALUE ONCLICK   ) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jQuery's [CSS function](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?

So adding a line such as this to the click listener could work:

```
$('html').css("background-image", "url(../images/bg1.jpg)");
```